# How to design an object to format text in different ways

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have a project that can print some data depending on some states and modes that the app is in.

```
enum Mode {
   mode1 = 0,
   mode2
};

enum State {
   state1 = 0,
   state2
};
```

Data can be printed in multiple ways, here is some examples:

```
1. name1 value1 name2 value2 name3 value3

2. value1 value2 value3

3. name1 : value1.  
   name2 : value2   
   name3 : value3
```

I tried to make a class with the ostream operator overload:

```
class Formater {
public:
   Formater(.....) { ... } // pass name, value, mode, state here.

   virtual void print_State1_Mode1(ostream& os) { }
   virtual void print_State1_Mode2(ostream& os) { }
   virtual void print_State2_Mode1(ostream& os) { }
   virtual void print_State2_Mode2(ostream& os) { }

    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Formater& f) {
        if (state1 & mode1) {
            print_State1_Mode1(os);
        }
        else if(state1 & mode2) {
            print_State1_Mode2(os);
        }
        else if(state2 & mode1) {
            print_State2_Mode1(os);
        }
        else {
            print_State2_Mode2(os);
        }

        return os;
    } 
};
```

This will be used for some commands and every command depending on the state and mode can have different format to print text.

So if my object cannot satisfy a command, I inherit from it and create a new one and override one of the virtual methods, depending for which mode and state I need a new format.

So I can end up with many more Formater objects (Formater1, Formater2....).

I am not 100% satisfied with this approach. Does anyone have a better design or ways I can improve my current design ?

Comment: What are the subclasses for? How does `Formater1` differ from `Formater2`?

Comment: Your `Formater` seems to encompass both format and data payload. Should they be separated out?

Comment: @ChristianHackl: it will have different print format for one of the state-mode ocmbinaiton that the base class would not support.

Comment: @Lingxi: in my opinion it should be togheter, but I am open to other suggestions.

Comment: So who decides which of the subclasses is chosen and why? I have the feeling that you should rely much more on simple free-standing non-member functions here. Don't over-engineer. It's hard to tell you something more specific because the question is too general.

Comment: The person who will use this object to implement the command that will generate this output. I am trying to avoid the many nested if else statements that can occur inside the command code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why this simple design does not suffice.

```
class Formatter {
  ...
  virtual std::ostream& insert(std::ostream&) const = 0;
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Formatter& fmt) {
    return fmt.insert(os); 
  }
};

class Formatter_State1_Mode1: public Formatter {
  ...
  std::ostream& insert(std::ostream&) const override;
};

class Formatter_State1_Mode2: public Formatter {
  ...
  std::ostream& insert(std::ostream&) const override;
};

Formatter* makeFormatter(Mode, State, ...);
```

It gets rid of the ugly if-else-ladder and yields better performance.

Comment: Yes, that sounds logical. However, the OP said in a comment that the total number of formatters is (mode count) * (state count) * (concrete class count), so something is amiss here; or the problem statement's description is wrong.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I guess it should be `concrete formatter count` = `mode count` * `state count`.

Comment: One command has (mode * state) count states. But there are multiple commands with different outputs.

Comment: @Kobe Anyway, that should not change the general design.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you using the `Bridge` pattern here. For that your functionality should be broken down into two pieces carefully. So your State should be the abstraction or refined Abstraction. And `Formatter` will be the `Implementor`. Then you can have different Formatters as `ConcreteImplementors`. You can use an `AbstractFactory` say FormatterFactory to get the Formatter based off of some config property. This logic should be defined by yourself.

Here's the `Bridge Pattern` definition by `Gang of Four`: decouple an abstraction from its implementation so that the two can vary independently.

Comment: Yes, let's over-engineer a simple output format problem like in a classical Java enterprise framework from the late 90s.